# Scala: TypeTag generated for an inner type inside a class doesn't match it's type

Tags: scala, reflection, inner-classes

If a class contains an inner class and a `TypeTag` for it is generated inside this class the generated `TypeTag` will contain the inner type which is "relative to the container" and does not match the `TypeTag`'s generic type parameter. E.g.:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
scala> class A { class B; val t = ru.typeTag[B] }
scala> val x = new A
scala> x.t
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[x.B] = TypeTag[A.this.B]
```

Here `x.t` is a `TypeTag[x.B]` but actually contains another type: `A.this.B`. The problem is that while the inner type is different for every instance of `A`, the type inside the `TypeTag` remains the same:

```
scala> val y = new A
scala> y.t
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[y.B] = TypeTag[A.this.B]

scala> x.t.tpe =:= y.t.tpe
res2: Boolean = true

scala> ru.typeOf[x.B] =:= ru.typeOf[y.B]
res3: Boolean = false
```

Is this behaviour intended by design or this issue could be resolved in later versions (my version is 2.11.7)?

One workaround for this problem is to generate the `TypeTag` outside the container class:

```
scala> def tt(a: A)(implicit t: ru.TypeTag[a.B]) = t

scala> tt(x)
res6: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[x.B] = TypeTag[x.B]

scala> tt(y)
res7: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[y.B] = TypeTag[y.B]
```

Are there any other workarounds?